# How to pass value of function and parameters to smart contract ethersjs?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, ethers.js

I am trying to interact with my smart contract using the ethers.js library, but an error appears when I try to call a function from the smart contract that takes the value of the transaction and a _count parameter.

Error I get:

```
Error: invalid BigNumber value 
(argument="value", value={"value":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x016345785d8a0000"},"_count":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x02"}}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.6.2)
```

Smart contract code:

```
function mint(uint256 _count) payable external returns (uint256) {
    ...code...    
    if (msg.value != price * _count) {
            revert IncorrectPrice(msg.value, price * _count);
    }
   ...code...
}
```

Ethers.js contract call:

```
await contract.mint({
        value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.1"),
        _count: ethers.BigNumber.from(2),
});
```

Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can put the function arguments inside the object. Try this

```js
await contract.mint(2, {
        value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.1")
});
```